# How can I define when a NSOperationQueue will send the next job

Tags: nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I would like to add multiple NSOperations to a NSOperationQueue , but be in control of when the next operation will be sent.

How can I configure the NSOperationQueue to "delegate" a "send next job" method to the owner of the NSOperationQueue

Answer (score 0):

You can do this: You can setup two NSOperations and make one dependent on the other and add it to the same queue. The first is a dummy operation and triggering that will trigger the second operation. So you can add all the instances of the second operation to the queue and whenever you want to trigger it, just add the first operation to the same queue and it will trigger the second operation immediately (since the first one is dummy and blank).